# meaning of jquery code

Tags: jquery, expression

I am trying to understand how these jquery code work

```
function findVideoForElement(el) {
      var parentControls=$(el).parents('.video_controls[rel]');
      if (parentControls.length==0) {
            return $('video[id=]');
      } else {
            return $('#'+parentControls.attr('rel'));
      }
}
```

When `parents()` is called ,it returns the elements matching the expression `'.video_controls[rel]'` .What exactly does this expression mean.Is it `class="video_controls"` ? I could not figure out what the `[rel]` part means.

Also,does `$('video[id=]')` mean element with id="video" ?

What would `$('#'+parentControls.attr('rel'))` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `'.video_controls[rel]'` means "has the class `video_controls` and has a `rel` attribute defined"
2. `$('video[id=]')` means "any `<video>` tag with an `id` attribute set to the empty string.
3. `$('#' + parentControls.attr('rel'))` would return the element with an id equal to the `rel` attribute on the parentControls element.

For more information on jQuery selectors, you can consult their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: `$('video[id=]') means "any <video> tag with no id attribute set.` --- curious, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It's just the way the selector works, you're selecting all video elements ="", whether or not the quotations are present, you're looking for an empty string

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken, it matches any `video` tag with an `id` set to an empty string, but will not match a `video` tag with no `id` attribute at all. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonypawks/YtH4c/

Answer (score 3):

You're right about the class="video_controls", it's looking for all elements that have something like the following. The [rel] just ensures that it has an attribute "rel"

```
<div class="video_controls" rel="whatever">
```

the $('video[id=]') is just looking for a video, with id=""

The $('#'+parentControls.attr('rel')) translates into $('#whatever') from the rel tag above, so it's looking for an element with the ID of the rel attribute on the .video_controls element

Comment: So ,if there are two video elements with ids `'whatever'` and `'another'` ,will  `$('video[id=]')` match `'another'` ?

Comment: Negative, because $('video[id=]') is looking for elements that have <video id=""></video>, Don't ask me why that would be there, but that's what it's looking for. My guess, is that that is the default player, in case of some sort of error

Answer (score 2):

It's basic CSS, `[rel]` refers to any element with a `rel` attribute.

`.attr("rel")` therefore returns the value of that `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

1. `$(el).parents('.video_controls[rel]');' returns all parents of`el`that has a class`.video_controls`with`rel` and it returns an array of parents.
2. `$('video[id=]');` returns `video` tag with no `id`.
3. `parentControls.attr('rel')` returns `rel` attribute of parents selected mention in first point.
4. `$('#'+parentControls.attr('rel'));` is a selector with `id`, here `#` means the id selector